# State of a linear vector space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, quantum-states

I was going through a lecture on linear vector space. It embodied all the examples of a linear vector space like it could be function spaces or vectors or real entities. But what exactly is meant by the 'state' of a linear vector space?

Comment: Could you clarify more what do you mean by "state" of a linear vector space?

Comment: A state is a vector, no?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "state" of a linear vector space.A state in QM generally defines all observables(postion,momentum) of a system which are represented in linear vector space to do math and obtain results or to define next state from current state with knowledge of rules to be applied to that specific system.

Answer (score 0):

States are the vectors living in a vector space. In quantum mechanics, the state vectors live in Hilbert space, which is also a linear vector space with a few more subtleties.